# How to refactor a function replacing an argument pattern match

Tags: elixir

I have this function:

```
def update(%Evento{} = evento, attrs, dataSchema) do
    evento
    |> dataSchema.changeset(attrs)
    |> Repo.update()
end
```

that is tied to the `%Evento{}` struct.
I would like to make it independent of the struct and pass an argument instead, so that when calling the function I could pass `%Evento{}`, `%News{}`, `%Contact{}`or whatever struct I want, while keeping the same functionality/pattern match check.

Comment: Why not just remove `%Evento{} =` from the pattern? If you only want to accept structs, then `def update(%{__struct__: _} = struct, attrs, dataSchema) do`. Or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: @Dogbert You're right. I only want to accept structs. Could you please turn this into an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can accept any struct as argument using the pattern `%_{}`:

```
def update(%_{} = struct, attrs, dataSchema) do
  ...
end
```

Alternatively, you can accept a whitelisted set of structs using the pattern `%module{}` and a guard:

```
def update(%module{} = struct, attrs, dataSchema) when module in [Evento, Foo, Bar] do
  ...
end
```

Edit: Updated to use the new `%module{}` pattern as suggested by Łukasz Niemier in comments!

Comment: Personally I think that `%module{}` syntax is much more convenient than `%{__struct__: module}`.

Comment: @ŁukaszNiemier thanks, I forgot those were added to Elixir recently! I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

While the answer of @Dogbert is [as usual] perfect and self-explaining, I would put here a bit more cumbersome approach, that permits callbacks for different kinds of input modules, still being 100% DRY:

```
defmodule DryStructMatch do
  defmacrop clause!(name, mod, fun) do
    quote bind_quoted: [name: name, mod: mod, fun: fun] do
      ast = {:%, [], [{:__aliases__, [alias: false], [mod]}, {:%{}, [], []}]}
      quote do
        def unquote(name)(unquote(ast) = struct, _arg1, _arg2) do
          result = struct # |> ... COMMON BLOCK
          unquote(:"#{name}_callback")(unquote(fun), result)
        end
      end
    end
  end

  @doc ~S"""
  Usage:

      use DryStructMatch, update: [Foo, Bar: &IO.inspect/1]

  The above will be expanded into two `update` clauses, the former having
    no callback, and the latter having a callback that spits the result
    out to console before returning it (due to `&IO.inspect/1`.)
  """
  defmacro __using__(opts) do
    Enum.flat_map(opts, fn {name, mods} ->
      [
        quote do
          defp unquote(:"#{name}_callback")(fun, result)
            when is_function(fun, 1), do: fun.(result)
          defp unquote(:"#{name}_callback")(_, result), do: result

          def unquote(name)(struct, _arg1 \\ nil, _arg2 \\ nil)
        end |

        Enum.map(mods, fn
          {mod, fun} -> clause!(name, mod, fun)
          mod -> clause!(name, mod, nil)
        end)
      ]
    end)
  end
end
```

What we do here is: we declare as many clauses as specified in parameters to the call to `__using__(opts)` macro. For the sake of simplicity, this example does not allow to pass common `block` (it’s hardcoded,) but it’s easy to modify the code accepting different common blocks as well.

Let’s test it:

```
defmodule Foo, do: defstruct foo: 42
defmodule Bar, do: defstruct bar: 42
defmodule Baz, do: defstruct baz: 42

defmodule A do
  use DryStructMatch, update: [Foo, Bar: &IO.inspect/1]
end

defmodule Test do
  def test do
    IO.inspect A.update(%Foo{}) # prints %Foo{foo: 42} (explicit)
    A.update(%Bar{})            # prints %Bar{bar: 42} (callback)
    A.update(%Baz{})            # raises `FunctionClauseError`
  end
end

Test.test
```

The latter will successfully call `update` for the first and the second lines in `Test.test/0`, failing for the third one:

```
%Foo{foo: 42}
%Bar{bar: 42}

** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in A.update/3    

    The following arguments were given to A.update/3:

        # 1
        %Baz{baz: 42}

        # 2
        nil

        # 3
        nil

    iex:17: A.update/3
```

Hope this could be helpful.